# Determine if request is PartialView or AJAX request in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, httprequest

I have to give access rigths to the users of a website.
I am doing the filtering here:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
}
```

The problem is that I cannot distinguish full View request such as 'Index' from PartialViewRequests or AJAX calls requests.

Therefore the page `'Index'` has access but the `'PartialViewGridViewForIndex'` does not have access.

The property `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` does not help either.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use the [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) extension method to determine if an AJAX request was used to invoke this controller action:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // the controller action was invoked with an AJAX request
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works. However I cannot wonder to ask myself if the partial view rendering is done by AJAX request. Do you have any ideea ?

Comment: The `IsAjaxRequest` tells you if the current request was an AJAX request.

Comment: And if I want to know if it is a PartialViewRequest ?

Comment: There's no such notion as `PartialViewRequest` in ASP.NET MVC. Controller actions might return a `PartialViewResult` for example or a normal `ViewResult`. If you need to know whether the controller action returns a partial view you cannot do this inside the `OnActionExecuting` method because this method runs **before** the controller action has ran. You could do it inside the `OnActionExecuted` method where you could inspect the concrete type of `filterContext.Result`. For example `if (filterContext.Result is PartialViewResult) { ... }`.

Comment: I recently had to perform a check to see if the request was a partial result and had onexecuting too, it's possible to determine if it's a partialview, by using the action and the controller from the routedata you can see if they match the requested url since the request.url doesn't change when you perform an action that returns a partial view. However you need to take the routing into account, example: using default routing (controller/action(id)) and calling ~/user the index will not show up in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend HttpRequestExtensions in asp.net Core 2 as below

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    private const string RequestedWithHeader = "X-Requested-With";
    private const string XmlHttpRequest = "XMLHttpRequest";

    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            return request.Headers[RequestedWithHeader] == XmlHttpRequest;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it as

```
 if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
    //----
  }
  else
  {
      // -------
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Authorization filter by extending the `AuthorizeAttribute`.  I would then put my code in the `OnAuthorize` override.  In the `FilterContext` object you can look at `FilterContext.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.ReturnType.Name`.  For a partial view this will be `PartialViewResult`.