# How to prevent HttpRequestValidationException when calling IsAjaxRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 and have Actions that need to accept input that includes HTML tags.  The Actions are only accessible by trusted administrators, so I allowed the HTML tags by adding the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute to the relevant Action methods.

This worked fine initially, but subsequently I have added code to Global.asax to prevent Forms authentication redirection for Ajax requests:

```
if (FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}
```

After adding this code, I started getting an `HttpRequestValidationException` on these Actions, thrown from `IsAjaxRequest`:

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (...).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Item(String key)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
   at MyApp.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
...
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried [`AllowHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) on your model property?

Comment: Or alternatively, write your own method, all this one really does is check the `X-Requested-With` is set to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @DavidG - AllowHtml surely won't help, as the exception is thrown before model binding.  What would my own implementation look like?  I.e. what would I do that is different from the current implementation, which from ILSpy looks like `return request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest" || (request.Headers != null && request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")`?

Comment: Hmm you may be right, I'm not near a machine to test it out unfortunately. Another possibility is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147

Comment: I think this is a bug in the `IsAjaxRequest` method, and as you suggested I can write my own method without validation as `return request.Unvalidated["X-Requested-With"] ...`.  I've opened an issue on GitHub for this as the latest source looks the same: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/114

Comment: @Joe: Will this works?: [Determine if request is PartialView or AJAX request in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892112/determine-if-request-is-partialview-or-ajax-request-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: What in the world does 'SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect ' have to do with validating input????

Comment: @Simon_Weaver `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` has nothing to do with it, except that it's the reason I need to test for an Ajax request.  The exception is thrown before that, in the call to `IsAjaxRequest`, as you can see from the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` is breaking this option in web.config:

```
<pages validateRequest="false"
```

I had the exact same situation and putting `[AllowHtml]` on my password field fixed the issue.

Either one of two things is true:

1) `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` did disable the effect of `validateRequest=false`

2) It never worked in the first place.

Not sure which is true but now it works.

Comment: What do you mean by the "exact same situation".  Are you saying you were calling `IsAjaxRequest` in `Application_BeginRequest`?

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about where you were doing this. But I had only very recently added the Suppress property and started having this issue with a customer who had < symbol in their password. I can delete this answer. Any luck yet?